# Hola, como arreglar mi código para que funcione más rápido en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy programando en C++ y necesito saber como optimizar el tiempo de respuesta de mi código, el problema dice que tengo que determinar el numero de fichas de un juego de dominó que tiene N números de puntos en una parte de la ficha.

```
int cant,aux;
double sumatoria=0,max=0;  
float aux1; 

cin>>cant;

for (int i=0; i<cant; i++){
    cin>>max; 
    for(int j=1;j<=max+1;j++){
        sumatoria+=j; 
    }
    cout<<sumatoria<<endl; 
    sumatoria=0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Puedes cambiar el `for` anidado por una suma de progresión aritmética:

```
for (int i=0; i<cant; i++){
        cin>>max; 
        
        //for(int j=1;j<=max+1;j++){
        //    sumatoria+=j; 
       // }
        
        // suma de progresión aritmética
        int maximoTerminos = max + 1;
        int primerTermino = 1;
        int ultimoTermino = max + 1;
        sumatoria = (maximoTerminos*(primerTermino + ultimoTermino))/2; 
        
        cout<<sumatoria<<endl; 
        sumatoria=0; 
    }
```

[Referencia](https://www.sangakoo.com/es/temas/suma-de-terminos-de-una-progresion-aritmetica)

Answer (score 0):

El número de fichas de un dominó, es la sumatoria de 1 a `n`, siendo `n` la cantidad de elementos y cuya formula es :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces solo tienes que aplicar la formula

```
cin>>max; 
int sumatoria = (max * (max +1)) / 2;
```